# Publish and subscribe an application as an API in WSO2 AM-1.7.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a **Timesheet Entry** application which needs to be exposed as an API which the users shall use for entering their effort time for assigned tasks.I have the following queries:

1. I have the login authentication created as a restful client which I have published and currently subscribing with JSON message as response.How to open up this service in the UI, so that the user gets the usual page for the authentication.
2. How to access this API from different user systems?Does the user has to login to the WSO2 Store everytime he wants to use this API?
3. The WSO2 docs mention to create users and roles, but since there will be around 10K users for this, how to do this to make the user feel that its the same application as before?

Answer (score 0):

Users are not required to log into the store. Only the application developer has access to the store.Application developer gets the consumer key/secret pair from store and embeds it in the web Application.

Application users/subscribers do not need to be aware of the API store.  When they use/login to the application, access tokens can be generated  using the embedded consumer key/secret pair based on a specific grant type ( Eg: Password) and access the service exposed via the API.

It is not required to create users and roles manually. If there exists a user store , you can integrate it with WSO2 API Manager.   [1] explains how to integrate a user store.

You can refer to the sample [2] to get an idea of how this is done in WSO2 API Manager.
This sample demonstrates a scenario where various services of a deployed web application are accessed via APIs created in API Manager.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Configuring+User+Stores

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Invoking+APIs+using+a+Web+App+Deployed+in+WSO2+AS